# java: how to extract values from a Map<String,Collection<Map<String,String>>>

Tags: java

I inherited some code and there is a map which is defined as `Map<String, Collection<Map<String, String>>>`

Here is a sample set of values stored in this map:

```
{
    A1: [
        {Item Number: "1234",Tax Code: "1"},
        {Item Number: "2345",Tax Code: "2"},
        {Item Number: "1234",Tax Code: "1"}
    ],
    B2: [
        {Store Number: "111",Status: "2"},
        {Store Number: "222",Status: "3"}
    ]
}
```

How can I get, say, A1.Item Number as a list of strings? I was planning to covert this to json and use json path. But since the map itself is available to me, is there an easier way?

I am using java 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can make a start by getting the value corresponding to `A1`: `myMap.get("A1")`.  What's next?

Comment: hi oliver, i did write a few lines of code to get the list of maps, then iterate through item, then get the values for the required key and add to the list i wanted. someone suggested there could be an easier way in java 8 using "streams". i am not familiar with this concept, i searched and couldn't get a clear understanding. hence thought of asking here

Comment: You should probably update/rewrite your question accordingly then.  i.e. "here is my iterative solution, but I can't figure out how to use streams".

Comment: A `Map<String,Collection<Map<String,String>>>` is a horrible construct. When you have more than 2 data structures nested (Map, Collection, Map), you should refactor your code to use custom Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the required result like so:

```
String itemNumber = "1234";

List<String> result = 
       myMap.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(itemNumber))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is most likely to be used numerous times, in which case it would be wise to encapsulate the logic into a method as such:

```
static List<String> getListOfValuesByItemNumber( 
            Map<String, Collection<Map<String, String>>> map,
            String itemNumber){

        return map.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Map::entrySet)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(itemNumber))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then simply pass a reference to the map and the item number as the second parameter and retrieve back a list of values where the map entry key is equal to the item number.

---

Further, a non-stream approach would be:

```
static List<String> getListOfValuesByItemNumber(
            Map<String, Collection<Map<String, String>>> map,
                                                     String itemNumber){
         List<String> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
              map.values()
                 .forEach(collection -> 
                         collection.forEach(m -> m.forEach((k, v) -> {
                             if(k.equals(itemNumber))
                                 accumulator.add(v);
                         })));
         return accumulator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

```
public static List<String> extractFieldValues(
    Map<String, Collection<Map<String, String>>> horribleMess,
    String fieldName) {

    return horribleMess.values()
                       .stream()
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                       .map(map -> map.get(fieldName))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But as indicated in a comment above, a Map/Collection/Map nesting is a maintenance nightmare you should get rid of through refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is,

```
List<String> ItemNumberLists = ( map.values() ).stream()
                                               .flatMap( Collection::stream )
                                               .map( s -> s.get("a") )
                                               .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

If you still doubt ask in a comment.